# USB Body cam file access? CammPro i826 / GoPro 9FF2 [Digital Photo Display]

Tags: usb, usb-drive

i plugged the device in my Ubuntu 20.04 system and it was found but I could not open it in the "files" application (used to be called nautilus)

strangely this is the first device that I could plug into a windows system and it just works but on my Linux system it does not... (typically i have the opposite experience )

So the device is a "***CammPro I826***"

When I run lsusb it is listed as "***GoPro 9FF2 [Digital Photo Display]***"

I just need to be able to access the files on the device to copy and delete them to make room for more footage on the device... I am not trying to use it as a webcam or anything like that... I am just after file access but I am not sure what to do to gain it.

**More Information Update**:
the manufacturer has only made drivers for mac and windows.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Does it have Ubuntu drivers?

Comment: @david no ... see update info in post

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I might have to replace this device with something else if it can't be accessed without drivers

Comment: @kbuilds I have not tried yet but wondered if it would work either via Wine or perhaps a virtual machine copy of windows...

Comment: @CrandellWS Trying with Wine is a good idea. From what I can tell, the drivers are necessary because it would allow an administrator to prevent a user of the body camera from deleting data without the proper permissions. A USB-type storage device does not have this ability. I suspect that most reparable cameras would be set up this way.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my notes to this answer in case it helps someone else get further along.

I tried installing the drivers via Wine. These are the drivers I installed:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U66K4zFX335g-WtYpIwyxENN7_DW8q7J/view

No luck. The application loads, but it could not detect that the camera was connected to the computer.

> Note that I did not take a very close look at the origin of these drivers. I would normally not run executables from a Beijing-based company on an important computer.

I took a look at the readme file, and there was something interesting there:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X2_bQkkY1qPzPxP8KWqfUeL8lGoxIyf5/view

This part is the most interesting:

> 5. Camera memory can be directly visited as a generic USB drive when camera in password free mode or password entered on camera.

The camera comes with the password protection off, but I also tried enabling the password, then entering it when the camera is plugged into the computer.

> The default password is 000000

But still, my Ubuntu machine could not detect the camera as a generic USB device.

The quote from the readme implies that the camera should be able to present itself as a generic USB device, which tells me that the driver might not be necessary.

Leaving these notes here in case they are helpful for someone else.

Comment: thanks for letting me know... as for generic USB device it acts as such on Windows making me think they have drivers built into the device that trigger the generic USB device mode... idk though...

Comment: I am downloading Windows ISO file to try with a VM will let you know results with reply... https://software.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/Win10_21H2_English_x32.iso?t=c0725211-9582-4681-baf0-ad638aad8dd6&e=1662694425&h=c7ff79c0cc054dffa1a61fbbde10c0015a8838852a33f3dacfa949f4d4f9f084

Comment: Windows virtual machine worked out the box without internet or activation... This is good enough for my needs... Let me know if you need help with this... I used Virt-manager .... and I did not install anything extra ... no applications or drivers... I just plugged it in ... feel to write in your answer and I will mark it ...